# Add third Party control in WPF using MVVM in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I want to add third party control in wpf using MVVM pattern.

I am trying to add like this

```
<StackPanel ItemsControl="{Binding PDFViewWPFControl}" ></StackPanel>

public pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF PDFViewWPFControl
{
    get { return _current_View; }

    set { RaisePropertyChanged("PDFViewWPFControl"); }

}
```

Comment: You're only calling `RaisePropertyChanged` in your set, whereas you should be setting a private variable too. Also, what is the nature of it's *not workingness*?

Answer (score 1):

StackPanel is a layout control, not a presenter.

Try this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding PDFViewWPFControl}" />
</StackPanel>
```

or you have to create a behavior or custom stackpanel, which add your control into stackpanel from codebehind.

Comment: Hi, I am able to add the third party control from code behind. I am not able to add using MVVM approach,      this is xaml code                                            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="PDFGrid" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="1024" Width="768" Background="red" >
                    <TabControl  Name="PDFTab"  BorderBrush="Silver"  UseLayoutRounding="True"  />
                </Grid>                this is code of  xaml.cs                                         PDFGrid.Children.Add(Current_View);   here is the control :-  public pdftron.PDF.PDFViewWPF Current_View { get; set; }